# jQuery UI Accordion - Each Panel Fit To Contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm using jQuery UI's Accordion http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ and I'm trying to get it to fit the height of each panels contents.

The way it currently works is to fit the largest panels contents, but I would like it to resize based on which panel is open.

Also, is there a way to make one panel open instead of the top one by default? I'd like to have the bottommost panel open when the user loads the page.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've tried putting `height:auto !important;` in the jquery-ui.css file on `.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active` which does work, but results in a weird issue when closing an accordion, where one stays open while the other is opening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ahh, found out they just have a setting for this! http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#no-auto-height

So basically, just do this: `$( ".selector" ).accordion({ autoHeight: false });`

Answer (score 26):

To keep things current, it seems that for jquery UI version 1.9, the autoHeight has been replaced by heightStyle.  http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-heightStyle

The way to do this after 1.9 would be `$( ".selector" ).accordion({ heightStyle: "content"});`

autoHeight still works under most circumstances, but I ran into difficulties in Chrome and Safari but not Firefox when I used autoHeight: false and my .ui-accordion-content included an image whose height was set to auto.  Using heightStyle instead worked much better.

Comment: Tested in Firefox as of June 3rd, 2014, I couldn't get the autoHeight to work but heightStyle works fine.

Comment: autoHeight Has been deprecated (documentation all over the place)

Answer (score 5):

Question is fairly old but now jQuery has option to set the height as per the content.
More information here: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-heightStyl

```
   $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
              {heightStyle: "content" }
            });
        });
```

Comment: One set of brackets too many {heightStyle: "content" } should be heightStyle: "content"

Answer (score 1):

this working for me

```
$(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            header: "h3",
            autoFill:true,
            autoHeight: false 
        });
    });
```